# Auto notify when a new update done on server in phonegap

Tags: android, ios, cordova

I am building a phonegap application using cordova latest version.

My application is working fine.

I want to let the people know. When a new update i do on my server, i want to give a push notification, even when the application is completely close in the user device.

Is there anyway i can auto notify on all installed devices in phonegap?

thank you! (In advance)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a service from google.
http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/index.html

That tells your app, if there are some changes on your server.
Therefore you have to install it on your server.